Entity Framework 8 Query Slower Than Direct Oracle Command
I'm currently working on a C# project where I need to retrieve data from an Oracle 19 database. I'm using Entity Framework to handle the database queries. However, I've noticed a significant performance difference between using Entity Framework 8 and executing a direct Oracle command.
Furthemore, EF generates a query with a script instead of simple SQL. I am no expert but could this be the issue ?
Why is there such a significant difference in performance between Entity Framework and direct Oracle commands?
Are there any optimizations I can apply to Entity Framework to reduce the query execution time?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here's a simplified version of my code:
var cnxStr = "......";

using UlisContext ulisRivpDc = new UlisContext( cnxStr );

string p = "PL/2672262";

double withAdo;
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using( var cnx = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection( cnxStr ) )
using( var cmd = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand( "select BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = :p", cnx ) ) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add( ":p", p );
    cnx.Open();
    using( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
        while( reader.Read() ) {
            //
        }
    }
}
withAdo = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "ADO : " + withAdo ); // 424.7524

using( var cnx = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection( cnxStr ) )
using( var cmd = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand( "SELECT BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = :p", cnx ) ) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add( ":p", p );
    cnx.Open();
    using( var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
        while( reader.Read() ) {
            //
        }
    }
}
withAdo = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "ADO (2nd time) " + withAdo ); // 433.4318

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

ulisRivpDc.BIEVAs.AsNoTracking().First();

sw.Restart();
List<BIEVA> it = ulisRivpDc.Database.SqlQuery<BIEVA>( $"SELECT BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD, BIDOS_NUM FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = {p}" ).ToList();
double withEfSqlQuery = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine("EF SqlQuery : " + withEfSqlQuery ); // 3416.5022
sw.Restart();
it = ulisRivpDc.Database.SqlQuery<BIEVA>( $"SELECT BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD, BIDOS_NUM FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = {p}" ).ToList();
withEfSqlQuery = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "EF SqlQuery (2nd time) : " + withEfSqlQuery ); // 1865.5861

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine( ulisRivpDc.Database.SqlQuery<BIEVA>( $"SELECT BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD, BIDOS_NUM FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = {p}" ).ToQueryString() );

// Sql Procedure generated by EF
/*
DECLARE
l_sql     varchar2(32767);
l_cur     pls_integer;
l_execute pls_integer;

BEGIN
l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_sql := 'SELECT BIEVA_NUM, BIPCD_NUM, BIPDO_NUM, BITEV_COD, BIDOS_NUM FROM BIEVA WHERE BIDOS_NUM = :p0';
dbms_sql.parse(l_cur, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, 'p0', N'PL/2672262');
l_execute:= dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
dbms_sql.return_result(l_cur);
END;
*/

sw.Restart();
it = ulisRivpDc.BIEVAs.AsNoTracking().Where( it => it.BIDOS_NUM == p ).ToList();
double withDbSet = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "DbSet FirstOrDefault (1st time) : " + withDbSet ); // 1876.4951
sw.Restart();
it = ulisRivpDc.BIEVAs.AsNoTracking().Where( it => it.BIDOS_NUM == p ).ToList();
double withDbSet2 = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "DbSet FirstOrDefault (2nd time) : " + withDbSet2 ); // 1864.8654
sw.Restart();
it = ulisRivpDc.BIEVAs.AsNoTracking().Where( it => it.BIDOS_NUM == p ).ToList();
double withDbSet3 = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine( "DbSet FirstOrDefault (3rd time) : " + withDbSet3 ); // 1870.6577

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(ulisRivpDc.BIEVAs.Where( it => it.BIDOS_NUM == p ).ToQueryString() );

/*
DECLARE
l_sql     varchar2(32767);
l_cur     pls_integer;
l_execute pls_integer;

BEGIN
l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_sql := 'SELECT "b"."BIDOS_NUM", "b"."BIEVA_NUM", "b"."BIPDO_NUM", "b"."BIPCD_NUM", "b"."BITEV_COD"
FROM "BIEVA" "b"
WHERE "b"."BIDOS_NUM" = :p_0';
dbms_sql.parse(l_cur, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':p_0', N'PL/2672262');
l_execute:= dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
dbms_sql.return_result(l_cur);
END;
*/

Here's the entity used :
[Table( "BIEVA" ), PrimaryKey( nameof( BIDOS_NUM ), nameof( BIEVA_NUM ), nameof( BIPDO_NUM ) )]
internal class BIEVA {
    public int BIEVA_NUM { get; set; }
    public int BIPCD_NUM { get; set; }
    public int BIPDO_NUM { get; set; }
    public string? BITEV_COD { get; set; }
    public string BIDOS_NUM { get; set; } = null!;
}

And the context :
class UlisContext : DbContext {
    private readonly string CnxStr;

    public UlisContext( string cnxStr ) : base() {
        CnxStr = cnxStr;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder ) {
        optionsBuilder.UseOracle( CnxStr );
    }

    public DbSet<BIEVA> BIEVAs { get; set; }
}


What you are comparing? ExecuteScalar without reading data from reader with full entity instantiation? Correct your tests, EF Core minimally slower than pure ADO.

Hello, I've edited the code and added the reader to make it more clear.
I am comparing the time for the query to be executed with ADO and EF. The time to instanciate de the entity is negligeable since I am only returning 1 row.
I've also ran some test with MySQL and I am not getting any performance issue.

You should Read exact values and create class with read properties. Only then you can compare speed.

Your ADO example isn't doing anything, it is just ticking through the row cursor. When you read entities EF is populating the set of entity objects to be consumed. Try creating your result collection then adding a new populated object read from your data reader for every row for a more meaningful comparison.
EF will almost certainly be slower than a hand-built scenario because the entire point of using EF is to provide a convenient solution to avoid spending the time to write and debug every hand-built query. An ORM provides convenience, and convenience will come at a cost.
As for methods to help improve performance, the primary way to ensure you are getting the best read performance from EF is to leverage projection for large read operations. For example if you are loading search results across a set of entities that form an aggregate root (many relationships) but your consumer just wants to cherry pick a few fields from the various related tables, use Select or a mapper that works with EF's IQueryable. Instead of fetching and materializing entire entities and eager/lazy loading related entities (resulting in either SELECT N+1 or Cartesian Products, both can be expensive for performance and/or memory usage) projection will build an efficient SQL statement to just pull back the fields needed for the consumer.
